# WPF: SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" + WindowState="Minimized" Bug

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I set the default properties of the window as:

`SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` and `WindowState="Minimized"`,

The window will have a **black** part on the right side.

To reproduce it try making a new WPF project and set the properties as stated above then add this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>HELLO</Button>
    <Button>HELLO</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

When you run it, it will look like this...

[image]

But in design mode, it looks fine..

[image]

If you try to resize the window, the buttons will snap into places and fix the layout. Or if you remove the either of the two properties, the black part will be gone.

Is there any work around for this? Is this a known bug?

Comment: I did it, and I end up with a minimized window, that when restored, is really tiny -- minimum window width + height of buttons and window frame. I tested it with VS2008 and .NET 3.5.

Comment: I just closed out my VS2015 solution and tried it there. Reproduced it! It happens up to 4.6. I dropped it down to 3.5, and it works as expected. So, apparently it is something about the newer framework.

Comment: Found this: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616008/wpf-sizing-is-broken-if-window-is-minimized

Comment: And another: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/841933/righthand-side-of-wpf-window-turns-black-after-laptop-goes-to-sleep . Both say they won't fix it even though it worked fine in 3.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in [Chris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334581), this is a known bug. It is simple to work-around though. Just add the following override to your window class:

```
protected override void OnStateChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStateChanged(e);

    InvalidateMeasure();
}
```

This will force WPF to redo the layout for the window when the window state changes, giving the correct results.

Answer (score 3):

It appears as though this is a known issue that they won't fix.

- [WPF sizing is broken if window is minimized](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/616008/wpf-sizing-is-broken-if-window-is-minimized)
- [Righthand side of WPF window turns black after laptop goes to sleep](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/841933/righthand-side-of-wpf-window-turns-black-after-laptop-goes-to-sleep)

> The WPF team has recently reviewed this issue and will not be addressing this issue as at this time the team is focusing on the bugs impacting the highest number of WPF developers. If you believe that this was resolved in error, please reactivate this bug with any necessary supporting details.
>
> We appreciate the feedback. However, this issue will not be addressed in the next version of WPF. Thank you.